# Can reverting to a previous Time Machine instance enable Keychain data access?

Tags: macos, time-machine, password, google-chrome, keychain

A client is running 10.9.5 on a ten year old Mac. They recently reset the admin password so that it is now different from their keychain password. They've got a bunch of passwords stored in keychain/Google Chrome that they desperately need. Chrome wasn't logged in/synced so I can't get the passwords from passwords.google.com

I've found out that without the old keychain password I can't access the keychain data.

I however noticed that they have a bunch of Time Machine backups. Can I revert to a previous backup and login or get the keychain data?

Comment: Have they forgotten the previous user or Admin password to the keychain?

Comment: Yes, they forgot the admin pass, so we reset it. Then the keychain pass was different from the user/admin pass, so we could no longer load the existing keychain data